# prolog Existance error: procedure does not exist

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

```
Existence error in user:nth1/3
! procedure user:nth1/3 does not exist
```

I have included module for lists : :- use_module(library(lists)).
but still getting this error..

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What prolog system are you using? I'm trying it in swi-prolog 5.8.3 and nth1/3 is available by default (the lists library autoloads).

Comment: SICStus 3.12.1 .. isn't it built in in sicstus?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SICStus, but looking in their web site I find that nth1/3 is present in SICStus 4 but not in SICStus 3. Can you use nth0 instead? The only difference is that it starts counting at 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[With SICStus 3, try using `nth/3`](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest3/html/sicstus.html/Lists.html#Lists) instead of `nth1/3` -- the latter doesn't exist in the `lists` library.

If your code actually calls `user:nth1( , , )`, then `nth1/3` (or whatever else you've prefixed with `user:`) needs to be defined in the `user` module for user-defined code, which it seems is not the case in your environment given the error you've described. If this is the case, try again without the `user:` module prefix. If the predicate is a system predicate and is definitely loaded, the PROLOG system should find it automatically. If it can't, PROLOG will then assume it's something you should have defined in the `user` module, hence why it may be looking there.